# pythonのrequestモジュールがimportできない

Tags: python, anaconda3, python-requests

初心者です。
PyCharmでpythonを使用しているのですが、requestモジュールがimportできずNo module...というエラー文が発生します。
requestsモジュールはインストールしましたし、パスも間違っていないはずなのですが...
ちなみにパスの確認はimport sys print(sys.path) print(sys.version)を実行しました。

ターミナルでの実行内容です

```
(base) info-no-MacBook-Air-4:~ takatsuka$ pip3 show requests
Name: requests
Version: 2.21.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: idna, certifi, chardet, urllib3
Required-by: Sphinx, conda, conda-build, anaconda-project, anaconda-client
(base) info-no-MacBook-Air-4:~ takatsuka$ cd PyCharmProjects
(base) info-no-MacBook-Air-4:PyCharmProjects takatsuka$ cd Fetcher
(base) info-no-MacBook-Air-4:Fetcher takatsuka$ python HtmlExtracter.py
['/Users/takatsuka/PycharmProjects/Fetcher', '/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa']
3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
(base) info-no-MacBook-Air-4:Fetcher takatsuka$
```

Comment: `import`文を記述しているPythonのコードも提示してください。エラーメッセージも省略せずに表示されたままを載せた方がいいでしょう。 / 文字で表示される情報はなるべく文字のまま投稿してください (画像にしてしまうと検索等ができなくなります)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。編集いたしました.

Comment: Pythonの出力が Anaconda ベースのものに見えますが、`requests` パッケージの表示に使っているのが `pip` であることに違和感があります。もしかして、 `pip` でインストールしましたか？

Comment: すみません、追記です。pipでのインストールが誤りだと気付いたので、condaコマンドでインストールしました。実際にディレクトリを直接目視でみても存在しています。ですがPyCharm上ではimportできません。使用しているpythonのバージョンも間違いではないのですが...

Comment: [こちらの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304041/how-to-retrieve-pip-requirements-freeze-within-python) を参考に、インストールされているパッケージを一覧するスクリプトをターミナルやPyCharmなどのそれぞれの環境で実行してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それを踏まえた上でもう一度質問を編集させていただきます